C++ CoRoutine First Try
Lazy range generator.
I know everybody's first example for co-routines.
But want to get some feedback.
The code
  #include <iostream>
  #include <coroutine>

  struct Handle
  {
      struct Promise;
      using CoRoutineHandle = std::coroutine_handle<Promise>;

      struct Promise
      {
          // Place to store the output value from yield and return.
          int   output;

          // This function is used to build the return object from the function.
          Handle get_return_object()                      noexcept    {return Handle{CoRoutineHandle::from_promise(*this)};}

          // Returning std::suspend_always by initial_suspend means no code is run at creation.
          // The co-routine is set up. The next call to resume on the handle will run the code to
          // the next yield (await) and thus return that value.
          std::suspend_always initial_suspend()           noexcept    {return {};}

          // This is called by co_yield.
          // Using std::suspend_always means the control is returned to the caller.
          std::suspend_always yield_value(int value)      noexcept    {output = value;return {};}

          // Return std::suspend_always to make sure
          // the co-routine does not exit prematurely and it is easy to detect that
          // we have reached the exit with promise.done()
          std::suspend_always final_suspend()             noexcept    {return {};}

          // This is called if there was an exception.
          // Needed but not used.
          void unhandled_exception()                      noexcept    {}
      };

      // Constructor keeps track of the handle.
      CoRoutineHandle  handle;
      Handle(CoRoutineHandle handle)
          : handle(handle)
      {}

      // Need to manually destroy the handle.
      // When we have finihsed using the Promise
      ~Handle()
      {
          handle.destroy();
      }

      // Move the co-routine to the next yield point
      // Or if no more yields to the final_suspend point.
      // Calling this after it returns true is UB
      operator bool() const
      {
          handle.resume();
          return !handle.done();
      }

      // Get the value out of the promise object.
      // Should only be called after a call to operator bool
      int get()
      {
          return handle.promise().output;
      }
  };

  // Hate having types with lower case letters.
  // So override the default type name
  namespace std
  {
      template<typename... Args>
      struct coroutine_traits<Handle, Args...>
      {
          using promise_type = Handle::Promise;
      };
  }

  // Define the co-routine.
  Handle myLazyRange(int b, int e)
  {
      while (b < e) {
          co_yield b++;
      }
  }

Then it can be used like this:
  int main()
  {
       auto range = myLazyRange();
       while (range)
       {
           std::cout << range.get() << "\n";
       }
  }

